# How can I display multiple details with a summary in RDLC?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I want to display a report in RDLC where a row shows the summary data of an invoice, and then by grouping on the invoice's Id as the parent class, it displays the details of the invoice (the products it contains).

[image]

This is the report (Sorry that it is in spanish). The First row is the summary of the invoice and the second is the subreport.

Finally, I am handling the report data through two DTOs, one related to the details and the other pertaining to the summary of the invoice.

Here I have a visual example of how I want it to look in case there are still any doubts.

[image]

And here's how it turns out when I do it:

[image]

I've tried creating a subreport with the details, which I invoke using the LookUp() function. However, I always end up with the same result: the invoice summary followed by a single detail, skipping the others.

I want to show all the details related to the Invoice.

Comment: Your subreport shouldn't need to use lookup - you should be passing the Invoice ID (or whatever ID) that's in the Summary and Detail datasets and getting the detail data. Lookup only returns a single value even when there are multiple values.

Comment: As Hannover suggested, you would typically build your subreport first so it accepts an Invoice No. as a simple parameter and then in your main report you would simply pass the invoice no. as a parameter. You don't need the master report to have any detail line information as that would get requested by the subreport.